# installing node js on web server

Tags: jquery, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I made simple chat application with node.js and socket.io
It's working in localhost:3000

But, I want to put it on my own website. I don't know how to install node.js package on web server. I am having mac.

Do you have any idea, how to do it?

Comment: What is the operating system that is running on your server...?

Comment: operating system is linux

Answer (score 4):

Grab the tarball from http://nodejs.org/download/, untar it `tar -xzf` to some directory, and then run it.

Or use a package manager as described [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager).

So as an example assuming you grabbed the latest 64-bit vers...

```
# go to a location where you'll install node
mkdir -p /app/nodejs
cd /app/nodejs
tar -xzf /path/to/node-v0.10.21-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

At this point, nodejs is in `/app/nodejs/node-v0.10.21-linux-x64`

Add the bin directory to your `PATH` (you can edit your `~/.bash_profile` or some other init script - for now this will just be for the shell session:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/app/nodejs/node-v0.10.21-linux-x64/bin`
```

Now you should be able to do npm install and the like.  It sounds like you may need to familiarize yourself with Linux basics - everyone needs to learn somewhere/sometime - I suggest you google around for a good tutorial that suits you.

Comment: I have downloaded that tar folder from the website. But after creating package file. when I am trying to run this command: npm install. Then It's showing me error like npm command is not found...

Comment: See edit.. you need to add it to your PATH

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't do this type of stuffs before. I am learning by doing things.

Answer (score 2):

http://nodejs.org/download/
Go there. Download it. Put the downloaded folder somewhere near your web pages and just reference it on your page.

You will reference on your page with something like this but instead of https link to google it will be a file path to where the folder is

Where the squiggle is could be different depending on where you place that folder. You shouldn't have to run any commands on it after it is downloaded

Comment: I have downloaded that tar folder from the website. But after creating package file. when I am trying to run this command: npm install. Then It's showing me error like npm command is not found... I am new in this. Can you please guide me how to reference that folder?

Comment: I edited and added more in my original answer.

Comment: I have no idea what happened, but I thought I was editing my post and ended up adding to yours..

Comment: Yea I saw that and was trying to figure out why mine looked so different than it did. No problem.